# Validate ActiveX textboxes in a form (not a userform) in a Word document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I created a form in Word. It is not a "userform1" type as in a VB project. It is written in the Word document.

I have been able to successfully have a user click the submit button and email the form (MS Word (NighlyReport.DOCM)).

I want to make each textbox required and if the user does not enter a value, I would like the "setFocus" to return the user to the textbox.

Since I am not using an official "userform" I do not seem to have this method available to return the user to the form.

I tried:
_Change
_GotFocus
_LostFocus
_KeyPress
_MouseDown

These work inside the textbox. None sends the user back to it.

I have a straightforward form to fill out and attach to Outlook. I would be willing to validate the textboxes with a commandbutton, but still cannot get the focus back to the textbox that was not filled out.

For the sake of simplicity, I am posting just two textboxes and my basic validation that is not working. To be clear, I am not using the userform grid, maybe that makes all of this impossible.

```vb
Private Sub txt1_Change()
    
If txt1.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "need your input"
Else
    Exit Sub
End If
End Sub
    
    
Private Sub txt2_Change()
    
If txt2.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "need your input"
Else
    Exit Sub
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: There is no need to activate the textboxes; simply use some prefix code in your 'submit' button to loop through them and test their contents and exit at either the first empty textbox or after having confirmed which textboxes are empty.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me so quickly. I've been banging my head searching for code that does not use 'userform' or validation without the 'control' event or property?

Comment: The closest I could get (which doesn't work) is the following loop: 'code' 
Private Sub Submit1_Click()
 For Each frm In Application.ActiveDocument 'Cannot use .Controls.
 If txt1.Value = "" Then
 MsgBox ("Please add something")
 Else
 Next
 Exit Sub
 
End Sub

Private Sub txt1_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub txt2_Change()

End Sub 'code'

Answer (score 0):

Try something along the lines of:

```
Dim iShp As InlineShape, StrOut As String
For Each iShp In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
  With iShp
    If .Type = wdInlineShapeOLEControlObject Then
      If .OLEFormat.ClassType Like "Forms.TextBox.*" Then
        If Trim(.OLEFormat.Object) = "" Then StrOut = StrOut & vbCr & .OLEFormat.Object.Name
      End If
    End If
  End With
Next
If StrOut <> "" Then
  MsgBox "The following controls have not been completed: " & StrOut
  Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: Macropod, I just tried it for my little example that I posted it it works!  I will integrate the concept into my real life form and keep you posted. Would you mind commenting on some of the lines of code?  For example, when I was scouring the web looking for solutions I would see "InlineShapes" and went right past it thinking that was not close to my solution.  I also read that using these activex controls wasn't the best idea, which I don't get, because they seem to be robust controls with lots of flexibility.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: ActiveX controls are inlineshapes of the OLE control type. Testing the Class Type enables the test to be limited - in this case to textboxes. Testing the Object allows one to find out if it's been filled in, and Name tells one which textbox it is.

Comment: Ok, so one more issue, I placed this in my code but it happens in this code above too - once all the text boxes are filled, the msgbox still alerts me that there with the same message, but with no textbox names.  I

Comment: The last issue I'm having with this example is when the two boxes are not empty, I still get the msgbox that states there are controls to fill out, but there's none in the list.I want to add this to my submit button which has another set of code to mail the 'real' form via outlook.  Should I create a sub and just call the sub from the submit button so it doesn't exit the sub that is shared with other code?

Comment: Simply enclose the message box & exit lines in an If test. See revised code.